# Translation operator and test function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Consider the translation operator $\tau_h, h\in \mathbb{R}$, on the space of test functions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}$. I would like to prove that for any $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$ \frac{1}{h} \cdot (\phi - \tau_h \phi) \, \to \phi' \quad \text{in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$} \quad \text{as $h\to 0$.}$$

I would like to use the characterization of the convergence in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ via compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ I'm stucked in how to approach the problem.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, for $\phi$ with support in $[-N,N]$ and $|h|<1$, both the translate and the original have support in $[-N-1,N+1]$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure about your conventions, so let’s say $(\tau_h\phi)(x)=\phi(x-h)$, so that the result is correct.

Let $F_h=\frac{\phi-\tau_h\phi}{h}-\phi’$ for $h \neq 0$.

We want to show that in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, $F_h \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. This means showing two things:

1. that there exists a compact subset $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $h_0>0$ such that for each $h$ such that $0<|h| < h_0$, $F_h$ has support in $K$.
2. that for every $n \geq 0$, $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\,|F_h^{(n)}(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.

For 1), just take $K=L+[-1,1]$ where $L$ is the support of $\phi$ (since $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$) and $h_0=1$.

Let’s see 2). For each $n \geq 0$, for each real number $x$, for each $h \neq 0$, $F_h^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\phi^{(n)}(x)-\phi^{(n)}(x-h)-h\phi^{(n+1)}(x)}{h}=-h^{-1}(\phi^{(n)}(x-h)-\phi^{(n)}(x)-(-h)\phi^{(n+1)}(x))$, so by Taylor, $$F_h^{(n)}(x)=-h^{-1}\int_x^{x-h}{(x-h-t)\phi^{(n+2)}(t)dt}=-h^{-1}\int_0^{-h}{(-t-h)\phi^{(n+2)}(x+t)dt},$$ thus $$F_h^{(n)}(t)=h^{-1}\int_h^0{t\phi^{(n+2)}(x-h+t)dt}=-h\int_0^1{t\phi^{(n+2)}(x-h+ht)dt}.$$

Finally, $|F_h^{(n)}(x)| \leq |h| \|\phi^{(n+2)}\|_{\infty}$, hence the conclusion.

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot! I only thing there's a typo when you calculate the $n$-th derivative of $F_h^{(n)}$; should it be the $n$-th derivative of $\phi$ applied to $x-h$?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out! That sort of argument is very important throughout distribution theory (it’s how you check the nice properties when you define more sophisticated operations such as convolution), so it’s important to have a good instance of it in mind.

Comment: I will keep in mind, thank you so much for your help and your advice!